# Best way to store html in a config file

Tags: php, quotes

I am writing my own download tracker and i want to offer users the ability to show a custom message on the download page. I want to allow html and javascript, so users can write a paragraph or use an ad code etc.

I am storing my settings in a config file (not the best way I know)

Example: `<?php define("WAIT_MESSAGE", "htmlcodehere"); ?>`

The problem is that quotes or slashes mess up the config file and the settings page will not load. I've looked into add slashes to try and escape these characters but it just adds multiple slashes.

What would be the best way to store html content/javascript in my config file?

EDIT: Have tried a few methods, but with all them quotes are escape each time i click save to update the config file \"hello\" becomes \"hello\" etc

Comment: What do you mean quotes or slashes mess up the config file  ?? What format is your config file ... can you put a sample of a smached config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Allowing users to actually insert HTML/Javascript/PHP in to your page is a very bad thing to do

Having said all that the problem is one that plagues us all from time to time. What you need is to store the HTML code in some format that is not going to change the meaning of the code above.

This problem is usually resolved by converting any such characters to their equivalent HTML entities so that you can safely store the

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php for more info.

Comment: Yeah the script will be self hosted by the user, its there own site they would be adding code to. Your answer works but quotes are being escaped still, every time the user hits save the quotes are escaped again. \"hello\" becomes \\"hello\\" etc.

Comment: @JoshFradley you have magic_quotes enabled, when designing a script that will hit different setups you should check for that with `get_magic_quotes_gpc()`, and handle the stripping of slashes accordingly.

Comment: Did you set the `ENT_QUOTES` flag when you called these functions. According to the documentation double quotes (") should be encoded as `&quot;` and single quotes (') should be encoded as `&#039;`.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone   Will this work? ``if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        $waitmessage = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST["waitmessage"]));
        $waitadcode = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST["waitadcode"]));
    } else {
        $waitmessage = htmlspecialchars($_POST["waitmessage"]);
        $waitadcode = htmlspecialchars($_POST["waitadcode"]);
    }``

Answer (score 2):

You should **NOT** trust your users so mutch that you let them post and save JavaScript and HTML on your site.

Comment: Its a script for use on their own sites, just want to let them customize a bit

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like with single ' ?

```
<?php define('WAIT_MESSAGE', '<p>Please wait.. your download starts shortly</p>'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not safe at all. Someone could easily inject PHP into it.

What you can do (which is a bit hacky), is to `base64_encode()` the data, and `base64_decode()` it when you need to use it. Doing that will get rid of the quotes/special characters problem, and the security problem.

Once you've written the base64_encoded HTML in the config file, to use it, you'll do:

```
<?php
    echo base64_decode(WAIT_MESSAGE);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would hold any editable values within a database to be safe,
but if you really want/need to edit a php config file then perhaps this is the safest way.

```
<?php 
/*Function to check if magic_quotes is enabled.
 (Stops double slashes happening)
*/
function check_magic_quotes($value){
    if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
        return stripslashes($value);
    } else {
        return $value;
    }
}

/*Form was posted, 
You should also do a check to see if logged in and have rights to edit*/
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
    //Check for magic quotes and then base64_encode the string.
    $value = base64_encode(check_magic_quotes($_POST['configVal']));

    /*Use heredoc to create the php line for the config & insert the
      base64 encoded string into place*/
$config=<<<CONFIG
    <?php define("WAIT_MESSAGE", '$value'); ?>
CONFIG;

    file_put_contents('someConfig.php',$config);
}


//When you want to include the config
include('someConfig.php');

/*To echo out the config value: base64_decode it,
  and then htmlentities encode it, to protect from XSS*/
echo 'This was included: '.htmlentities(base64_decode(WAIT_MESSAGE));


//Basic form with current value when someConfg.php has not been included
$config = file_get_contents('someConfig.php');
preg_match("#\"WAIT_MESSAGE\", '(.*?)'#",$config,$match);
 ?>

<form method="POST" action="">
  <p>Config Value:<input type="text" name="configVal" value="<?php echo htmlentities(base64_decode($match[1]));?>" size="20"><input type="submit" value="Update"></p>
</form>
```